# Add "This version" and "First version" in abstract

Tags: abstract

I am trying to add on separate lines "This version" and "First version". I have tried the following code, but it does not seem to work:

```
\renewcommand*{\today}{\normalsize{This draft: December 2018}} 
\renewcommand*{\newline}{\normalsize{First draft: March 2015}}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The ideal outcome would look like as follows:

[image]

Comment: It would also be more helpful if you post a pic of how you want your final output looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you need to define two commands in the preamble `\thisdraft` and `\firstdraft` which you are supposed to use later in your document. These commands includes the words of your choice (in your case "This draft: December 2018" and "First draft: March 2015"). Then 
place the commands as an arguments in the `date{}` commands of the article so that you ensure the commands output will be printed in the place designated for the `date{}` in the article title. The code will be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
%
\newcommand*{\thisdraft}{This draft: December 2018} % define command
\newcommand*{\firstdraft}{First draft: March 2015}  % define command
%
\title{Title}
\author{Name}
%
\date{\thisdraft \\ \firstdraft}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\hrule % optional rule after title

\begin{abstract}
Type your abstract here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Sec One}

\end{document}
```

The output will be:
[image]

You can later change the arguments of the commands `\thisdraft` and `\firstdraft` according to your needs.

Comment: In fact you can even automate the date in the command `\thisdraft` to print out the current month and year of your current document. To do this you shall need a little more details and using `datetime` or `datetime2` package and defining the desired format for date. Anyway just wanted to keep things simple at least to your present needs.

Comment: Thank you very much @hesham!! You were extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Why redefine such important commands? The commands `\today` and `\newline` that you are trying to re-define are mainly used in latex in many classes and packages definitions. Re-defining them may cause unnecessary issues.

You can use `\newcommand*{\mytoday}` and `\newcommand*{\mynewline}` instead a follows.

```
\newcommand*{\mytoday}{\normalsize{This draft: December 2018}} 
\newcommand*{\mynewline}{\normalsize{First draft: March 2015}}
```

and then use them in the text as `\mytoday{}` and `\mynewline{}`.

I would also suggest choosing a better command name (e.g. \mytoday --> \myversion and  \mynewline --> \myfirstversion).

Comment: Thanks very much, @hesham. I just tried your suggestion and still do not get the outcome.

Comment: Any further suggestions will be greatly appreciated, @hesham!

Comment: yes there is. plz wait